# Zoomable UIImageView

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uiimageview, zooming

I'm using this [library for zoomable UIImageView](https://github.com/huynguyencong/ImageScrollView/blob/master/Sources/ImageScrollView.swift).

Problem: When image width is smaller than screen width, it aligns to the left of the screen. After first attempt to zoom it is corrected.

I've searched and tried lots of answers and tried to fix this issue but seems its using the same way others propose.

here's the link to library source code :
https://github.com/huynguyencong/ImageScrollView/blob/master/Sources/ImageScrollView.swift

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use a simple `UIWebView`? This way you do not require any framework:

```
@IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

func loadImage(url: URL) {
    self.webView.stopLoading()
            let html = "<!DOCTYPE html>" +
            "<html>" +
            "<head>" +
            "<meta charset=\"UTF-8\">" +
            "<style type=\"text/css\">" +
            "img{position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; margin: auto; max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%;}" +
            "</style>" +
            "</head>" +
            "<body>" +
            "<img src='\(url)'/>" +
            "</body>" +
            "</html>"
    self.webView.loadHTMLString(html, baseURL: nil)
}
```

You can load files with remote URLs as well as files with local URLs. You can get a local URL for example like this:

```
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "image", ofType: "png")!)!
```

Comment: tested this but how to load UIImage without Saving it on disk first?

Comment: `UIWebView` can only show images by an URL. This requires the file to have a fixed local or remote location. But why is it a problem to save the image? You could for example save the file to a temporary directory. Maybe you should explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: first of all I could load the images into UIWebview via loadData or something ( i dont remember the syntax) and then its being used inside a cell of a pagerView (scrollable from right to left or vice versa) , this method cause lots of lags and uses lots of memory and it also conflicts with pagerView scrolling , i fixed this library by adding self.view.layoutIfneeded before displaying image , by the way thanks for your response